# Adequate name for a structure wrapping an array allocated on the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, naming

I am trying to figure out an adequate name for my structure that contains a heap allocated array without much success. The structure specifically cannot grow, so dynamic array is not adequate. I was thinking about calling it a heap array, but then it's ambiguous with the heap data structure (which is often represented in the form of an array no less).

The best suggestion until now I've had recommended is runtime array.

Edit:
I was planning to call it static array also, since it doesn't change size unless you free it and allocate it again, however that clashes with my static array which has its size fixed at compile time (I don't mind changing the name of the structure with an array with size fixed at compile time, but it has to make sense).

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @JackBashford I am using C++.

Comment: Use the [edit] link to edit your question in future, but it's always good to include the language tag in the original revision. (I've edited the tags for you)

Comment: @JackBashford I wasn't sure that was relevant to the question, but maybe it is. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The historical `dynarray` resembles your case, so "dynamic array" is probably OK.  Or "fixed-size dynamic array" to disambiguate the word dynamic.

Comment: `std::vector` ;)? Who cares that it can grow? It does what you need.

Comment: @L.F. Dynamic array seems to be used as a synonym to growable array. I think the most adequate naming is actually static array, but when what do I call the static array that has its size determined at compile time? Another issue is that C++ refers to static arrays as arrays with compile time fixed size.

Comment: @MarekR std::vector is growable, meaning that it can invalidate iterators after growing. I want my array naming to convey that this will not happen, unless you free it.

Comment: So do not change its size or simply wrap `std::vector` exposing only needed functionality. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @lightxbulb There are really two pairs of "static/dynamic" here: "fixed size/changeable size" and "compile-time size/runtime size".  `std::vector` is dynamic, dynamic.  `std::array` is static, static.  Your case is static, dynamic, and so is `dynarray`.  I guess that's where the ambiguity comes from.

Comment: @MarekR If you wrap it, you still have to come up with a convenient name. The question is about the naming, not about something else.

Comment: In other languages I would probably just call it `boxed_array`

Comment: Maybe "fixed size runtime array" then.

Comment: @KarolSamborski Boxed array seems to carry additional meaning, for example in Haskell.

Comment: `fixed_vector` might be a good name. IMO most probably wrapper is obsolete.

Comment: @L.F. I could write five words for it, but then it would be a pain every time I use it. I'll probably just go with your recommendation for dymanic array, since C++ already has std::vector for a growable array, and if I want a growable one I can always call it that.

Comment: I believe this question is primarily opinion based and should be closed.

Comment: @Fureeish Is there anything wrong with the fact that the question is subjective? I am more than happy to see a variety of opinions, so I can get an idea from those.

Comment: @lightxbulb - It's not wrong. Just off-topic for SO. Other venues may be appropriate for it.

Comment: Like StoryTeller stated - the question is simply off-topic for Stackoverflow and shouldn't have been asked here. It's not bad - it just does not fit here.

Comment: @StoryTeller What other venues would be better for this? I am not very familiar with many other programming related QA forums, so that's why I asked it here.

Comment: For one, SO is not a forum. There are no discussions here. Q&A need to be focused and fact based. Subjective content makes for poor Q&A's, since they get untamable. For discussions, reddit is one venue I personally like. It too has a voting system, and for many programming sub-reddits subjective content is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::array<T, length>>` ?